# How to install Android SDK under Windows

Tags: android, windows, installation

I I have all the basic setup files to install android, i have downloaded them from my office..

But the problem is, it downloads too much data during installation.....Because i have to install this at my home and my Internet connection is very slow so downloading might not possible....

I have  a desktop and not laptop so i also can not take it to office....

Of let leave story and come to point....Is there any setup available that i can download full sdk from my office so that i need not to connect to Internet at my home.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I doubt this is a question for stackoverflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install at your office, put the installed and updated android sdk on an usb stick.

Comment: You mean i intall sdk and  put that folder from my program folder to my penDrive?

Answer (score 1):

You can download anywhere. Android SDK will work just by copy/Paste the entire SDK folder.

Comment: Copy paste that folder under  programs Directory in my c drive?

Answer (score 0):

You can port android sdk to any other machine by just copy/paste only if you are running both with Windows OS(XP,Vista & 7). But it is different in linux or mac.

If you use Eclipse IDE for android development you have to provide the folder where you copied the android SDK in the project properties.